# Is it possible to add animation or visual indicators on dynamics 365 UI?

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I am trying to add a (colour-changing or changing images)visual indicator to dynamics 365 UI,to show sales manager how long a lead has been in the system.

Answer (score 0):

I think yes you can do so.
How, Here are 2 good links which will tell you how to use it.

- [Megan Walker Blog](https://meganvwalker.com/using-animated-gifs-dynamics-365/)
- [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/marketing/upload-images-files)

I personally like Megan walker's blog, she tries to give info in very simple way.

Comment: Thank You For The Help, I Will Explore these and give you feedback

Comment: if this helps could you please mark it as solved. It will help others as well.

Comment: Okay. . .I shall do that